# Spring web app encoding

Tags: java, spring, servlets, encoding

I'm currently working on a web application platform being called by other sites using POST forms. Some sites call us using UTF-8, others call us using ISO-8895-1. Since my application is in UTF-8, some of the characters passed by the calling sites appear weird on my side.

Ex: Montréal -> Montr�al

I tried to "convert" the string like this:

```
new String(request.getParameter("city").getBytes("ISO-8895-1"), "UTF-8");
```

But i'ts not working, I'm getting "Montr?al"

Is it possible to convert encoding like this?

Is it possible to use different request encoding depending of the calling site?

Comment: The encoding of the the POST can be dictated in the header. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Are you sure `ISO-8895-1`? It should be `ISO-8859-1`. 8895 -> 8859.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the encoding type is wrong in your case. `ISO-8895-1` should be `ISO-8859-1` (`8895 -> 8859`).